# Automatically filling in a form when a link is clicked on another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am making a website for a computer science project and have created a search function that lists data in an SQl database (based on the search text".

When I click on one of the listed values, I want it to automatically fill in an input box on another page.

I have already looked online and didn't really understand it all which is why I am asking.

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: post some of your code...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have something like:

on page1:

```
<a href="page2.php?foo=someText">link</a>
```

and on page2:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="text" name="..." value="<?= $_GET['foo']; ?>" />
    ...
</form>
```

You could also create a form in page1 to send data with the `POST` method (to hide data from within the URI).

What you should search is how to send and retrieve data with `GET` and `POST` methods.

With the `<?=` PHP tag you print (echo) the content of `$_GET['foo']` variable.

### Assumptions

But be careful, you **must** test variables before to print them (and avoid security issues)